# Stationary Distribution of Markov Chain

Tags: equation-solving, distributions, markov-chains

I'm trying to compute the stationary distribution of the following Markov chain:

$$P=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p_{11} & p_{12} \\
 p_{21} & p_{22} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I know you have to solve the equation:

$$\pi = \pi P$$

So, going through the standard approach...

```
pi = ( {
   {Subscript[pi, 1], Subscript[pi, 2]}
  } )
```

```
pi.P // FullSimplify

Out = {{p11 Subscript[pi, 1] + p21 Subscript[pi, 2], 
  p12 Subscript[pi, 1] + p22 Subscript[pi, 2]}}
```

And then solve the linear equations using the "Solve" command:

```
Solve[{p11 Subscript[pi, 1] + p21 Subscript[pi, 2] - Subscript[pi, 
     1] == 0,
           
   p12 Subscript[pi, 1] + p22 Subscript[pi, 2] - Subscript[pi, 2] == 0,
           Subscript[pi, 1] + Subscript[pi, 2] == 1}, {Subscript[pi, 
   1], Subscript[pi, 2]}] // FullSimplify
```

The thing is that I get no solution.

Why does this happen?

Comment: See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)  and [DiscreteMarkovProcess](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html) for info.

Comment: Don't be surprised if this question is closed as it seems to be more of a misunderstanding of the necessary assumptions.

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining variables. `Subscript[pi, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX). Yours is a recursive definition `pi = ( { {Subscript[pi, 1], Subscript[pi, 2]}})` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to impose restrictions on the probabilities:

$$0<\pi_1<1$$
$$0<\pi_2<1$$
$$\pi_1+\pi_2=1$$
$$0<p_{11}<1$$
$$0<p_{22}<1$$
$$p_{11}+p_{12}=1$$
$$p_{21}+p_{22}=1$$

There are at least two ways to obtain the stationary distribution:

```
Solve[{π1, 1 - π1} == {π1, 1 - π1} . {{p11, 1 - p11}, {1 - p22, p22}}, π1]
(* {{π1 -> -((1 - p22)/(-2 + p11 + p22))}} *)
```

and

```
Limit[{π1, 1 - π1} . MatrixPower[{{p11, 1 - p11}, {1 - p22, p22}}, n], n -> ∞,
  Assumptions -> {0 < p11 < 1, 0 < p22 < 1, 0 < π1 < 1}]
(* {{π1 -> -((1 - p22)/(-2 + p11 + p22))}} *)
```